# Pandas: perform mixed cross join and inner joins

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I am working with the following large dataframe `df` of 600,000 rows:

```
idx1    idx2    Val         
38      4       101         
38      23      103         
39      4       104         
39      23      105         
40      4       105         
40      23      106
```

`idx2` is same for each of `idx1`.

I need to perform join on `df` such that there is `cross join` on column `idx1` and `inner join` on column `idx2` to get the following:

```
idx1    idx2    Val idx11   idx21   Val1
38      4       101 39      4       104
38      23      103 39      23      105
38      4       101 40      4       105
38      23      103 40      23      106
39      4       104 40      4       105
39      23      105 40      23      106
```

I am not sure how to approach the above.

Comment: `df[a].merge(df[b], how='cross')` ?

Comment: What about idx2? Also I need to do this in an efficient way as I have 600k rows

Comment: Merge (or join, depending if it's '1:1') again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try #2:

```
df.merge(df, how='cross').query('idx2_x == idx2_y and idx1_x != idx1_y')
```

Output:

```
    idx1_x  idx2_x  Val_x  idx1_y  idx2_y  Val_y
2       38       4    101      39       4    104
4       38       4    101      40       4    105
9       38      23    103      39      23    105
11      38      23    103      40      23    106
12      39       4    104      38       4    101
16      39       4    104      40       4    105
19      39      23    105      38      23    103
23      39      23    105      40      23    106
24      40       4    105      38       4    101
26      40       4    105      39       4    104
31      40      23    106      38      23    103
33      40      23    106      39      23    105
```

Try this:

```
df.merge(df, on='idx1', how='outer').query('idx2_x == idx2_y')
```

Output:

```
    idx1  idx2_x  Val_x  idx2_y  Val_y
0     38       4    101       4    101
3     38      23    103      23    103
4     39       4    104       4    104
7     39      23    105      23    105
8     40       4    105       4    105
11    40      23    106      23    106
```

Comment: Almost correct but not 100% .. please see my desired output above. The outer join causes 38 to join on 38 and I want to display the idx1_y as well; but still great idea.

Comment: @Zanam See attempt #2.